# I need to add/update only claim under serviceprovider in wso2 (version 5.7) using soap request

Tags: wso2, soapui, wso2-identity-server

I need to add/update claims under service provider that is already created in wso2. Currently, I am using version 5.7 of wso2. So, I need a soap request to add this using soap web service.

Comment: You need to show your current effort. Please have a careful read through [ask].

Answer (score 2):

You can use IdentityApplicationManagementService SOAP Admin service to update Service Provider. Sample SOAP request information can be found [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Using+the+Service+Provider+API#UsingtheServiceProviderAPI-updateApplication).

Answer (score 0):

You can find the soap requests here

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Managing+Claims+with+APIs

Comment: Thanks senthalan, Now I am able to add/update claim of service providder using soap request.

Comment: By the way there is SOAP UI tools that tell us every things about wso2 soap request